# Как в Delphi получить HMAC SHA256 Base64 строки?

Tags: delphi, поиск-библиотек, base64, sha256, hmac

Есть строка `{"param":"value"}`, как получить ее HMAC SHA256 Base64?

Comment: [Не подходит?](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Hash.THashSHA2)

Comment: @OldSkull так и делал THashSHA2.GetHMAC(text, key, SHA256); и это верно.
Думал что это не верно, так как использовали разные ключи с проверяющей стороной.